# Use Python.exe located in a shared folder

Tags: python, windows

Sounds like a simple question, but I was not able to find an answer about that.
I have my python and the environment installed on a different machine but in a shared folder which is accessible via UNC path.
I wanted to use this python to run a python script from my machine (which is a different machine compared to the machine where the python.exe is installed).
So I tried the following in the command window:
`> \\servername\shared\environment\path\python.exe \\servername\path_to_script\myscript.py`

But it does not work and I get the following error message:

```
No Python at 'C:\ProgramData\conda\python.exe'
```

Seems to me that it tries to find the `python.exe` on my machine instead of using the `python.exe` in the share folder.
Is it not possible to run the `python.exe` which is located in a shared folder from a different machine?

Comment: Do you know that you can run executables off this network share at all? (This isn't always possible: Not all shared filesystems support `mmap()`, and even the ones that _can_ support invocation of executables aren't always configured to; there are sound security reasons, in particular, to disallow it in practice).

Comment: Assuming that this is supported in general, I'm curious whether the behavior you see is any different when the remote directory holding the executable is the current working directory of the shell in which you're doing the invocation. (I'd also start with `python --version` or another invocation that _doesn't_ involve running your script itself, and distinguish whether the problem extends to invoking _your script_ -- which, being unknown to us, may or may not involve starting a second interpreter as a subprocess -- or invoking _the interpreter itself_).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, I know. For my use case the security permissions are set in a way that executing an application is allowed.

Comment: BTW, while the answer you have currently is not great, it also _could_ be correct, if the "interpreter" on the network filesystem is not in fact a freestanding interpreter at all but instead a virtualenv that points to a local interpreter that _isn't_ itself stored on the network filesystem.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy good idea. I tried out `python --version` and I get the same error message `No Python at 'C:\ProgramData\conda\python.exe'`.

Comment: Is the interpreter on the network filesystem a real interpreter, or a virtualenv?

Comment: (To be clear, if it's a virtualenv, you need to create it with/from a "real" interpreter _whose executable is also on the network filesystem_)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, it is both of them. It is a venv, but contains also `python.exe` and all installed libraries.

Comment: The python.exe created by venv is not a real standalone interpreter; it refers back to the interpreter it was created from.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I read the thread, but is there a way to check if the `python.exe` is a real interpreter or not? And beside that the venv folder was not moved to the shared folder as described in the thread. It was created there from scratch in the shared folder. So, I doubt that it is not a standalone interpreter.

Comment: Hm. I have easy answers for that for more UNIXy platforms, but not for Windows offhand.

Comment: Looks like for modern  versions there's a `pyvenv.cfg` file in installations that are a virtualenv rather than a standalone interpreter; the `home` key therein points to the parent interpreter.

Comment: If it was created _with `venv`_, it's very much not standalone. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#how-venvs-work -- `sys.base_prefix` still refers back to the original interpreter, and, well, _you're seeing in practice_ that you can't start a venv-built interpreter where the base interpreter isn't reachable; if that restriction didn't exist, you would never have asked this question.

Comment: Also see https://peps.python.org/pep-0405/, specifying that base_prefix is used for loading the standard library (and thus that the venv is _not_ a fully standalone installation).

Answer (score -2):

It could be because of venv after updating python version. Delete the current one and create a new one, save all dependencies using pip freeze

Comment: Speculation is suitable for comments -- but an answer should be authoritative.

Comment: [We know exactly what we want to be](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/05/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/), and enforcing our rules helps us _be_ that thing. In the immediate case, this was an answer that was only half-right: correct that the problem was caused by the executable being a virtualenv, incorrect that creating a new virtualenv in the same way would help (since the problem is that the OP wants to create the virtualenv on machine A and use it on machine B connected by a network share, where B doesn't have access to the underlying interpreter).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Well OP didn't tell us about that stuff in the question, i had a similar problem, i assumed creating a new venv would help (it did in my case cuz it wasnt about network sharing but mismatch between venv version and python version). If it doesn't, OP could reply to me with more details then I'd reply back etc. How am I supposed to help OP if I can't communicate with him? This website significantly restricts new users being helpful man.

Comment: The OP _did_ tell us about that stuff in the question. "different machine but in a shared folder which is accessible via UNC path", "different machine compared to the machine where python.exe is installed", &c.